# Is the relation a function on Z?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Thanks for stopping by and looking at my question.

There's a question from my homework assignment I completed last week that was graded and returned to me today.

***HW question:***

"Consider the relation $R=\left \{ \left( 2x, x^2 \right) : x \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is the relation $R$ a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$?  Explain."

***My answer:***

"For $R$ to be a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$, $R \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$.  If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\left( 2x, x^2 \right) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $\left( 2x, x^2 \right) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.  Thus, $R$ is a relation on $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can say it is a relation from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$."

My answer was marked wrong with the following feedback from my professor:

"No, since the domain of $R$ cannot be $\mathbb{Z}$."

I went back to my notes trying to understand, but I'm clearly missing something; could somebody please expand on the professor's feedback?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The domain of $R$ is the set of all first coordinates of ordered pairs in $R$, so it’s $\{2x:,\in\Bbb Z\}$. That’s the set of even integers, which is clearly not all of $\Bbb Z$. $R$ is functional, meaning that if $\langle x,y_1\rangle$ and $\langle x,y_2\rangle$ are both in $R$, then $y_1=y_2$, and its codomain is $\Bbb Z$, so it’s a function from some set to $\Bbb Z$, but that set isn’t $\Bbb Z$: it’s the set of all even integers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a function $f:X\to Y$ can be represented by (or is defined to be) a subset $F\subseteq X\times Y$. However, not all such subsets represent a function; there is an additional condition, namely that for each $x\in X$ there should be exactly one $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in F$.

In your example, $R$ isn't a function because it doesn't satisfy this condition (I'll leave it to you to check this).

Answer (score 1):

A function can be defined indeed as $R\subseteq X\times Y$, however the following criterias must be met.

1. For all $x\in X$ there exists a $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$
2. For all $x\in X$ and $y,z\in Y$ such that $(x,y)(x,z)\in R$ implies that $y=z$

Your relation fail on the first one, try to find a $y$ such that $(3,y)\in R$, it doesn't exist and hence it isn't a function.